# How do I map the value in php?

Tags: php, mapping

I am trying to write the best mapping codes in my project

I have some 1 on 1 mapping spreadsheet

something like

```
projectA            projectB
taskA                task1
taskB                task2
taskC                task3
taskD                task4
taskE                task5
```

The value I got from my DB is `task1` to `task5` but I want to display them in `taskA` to `taskE`

I have few ideas for mapping

```
switch($var){
  case 'task1':
     return 'taskA'
  break;
  case 'task2':
     return 'taskB'
  break;
  ….more
}
```

or creating an array

```
$map = array('task1 => taskA, 'task2' => 'taskB…more)
```

then match the key and get the value.

I am not sure if there are better ways to do this. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Define 'better' in 'better ways'.

Comment: do the numbers in project b directly correlate to the index of the letter in project a?

Comment: Keep using associative arrays. The origin of its usage what you called mapping. Suppose the switch with Task5, It should have make 5 conditional checks before getting the value, while an associative array will carry it the memory address of the value directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can play with the string functions

idea is  get the last char from your projectB :

if you have  'task1', the last char is '1'
then you can create a new char'A' by  ASC code of '1' + 16
after that you can replace the old string or make new string 'taskA'

a little lazy did no find the exact functions you need lol

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Benny, but here is the code:

```
return chr(intval(substr($var, 4, 1)) + 64);
```

Where $var is either task1, task2 etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to functionally generate this data:

```
<?php
function convertTaskNumberToLetter($task) {
    // get digits at the end of a string
    $digits = ereg_replace('^[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+)$', '\\1', $task);

    $numArr = str_split($digits);

    $result = '';

    foreach ($numArr as $digit) {
        $result .= chr($digit + 64);
    }

    // return the updated string
    return str_replace($digits, $result, $task);
}

$taskList = array('task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4', 'task 5', 'task99', 'task999');

$updatedTaskList = array_map('convertTaskNumberToLetter', $taskList);

print_r($updatedTaskList);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => taskA
    [1] => taskB
    [2] => taskC
    [3] => taskD
    [4] => task E
    [5] => taskII
    [6] => taskIII
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping array just like you said. This doesn't sound like something where performance is critical, so there's absolutely no need to go out of your way to create something 'clever.'

Use a solution that is clear and simple to understand, because not only will it be easier to debug when things go wrong, but one fine day you (or someone else) will need to come back and make sense of your code, and that'll be a heck of a lot easier without the unnecessarily clever bits.